# Port Forwarding without delay and high fps in a real time live stream using socat

Tags: port-forwarding, streaming, real-time, socat

I am using the command `socat` to port forward a connection from a real-time live stream.

```
TCP4-LISTEN:8080 TCP4:123.456.789.12:80
```

The problem is it has added delay and low fps while the live stream without port forwarding works perfectly without delay and high fps.

- What might it be causing this?
- Is there a way to fix this configuring `socat` or should I use another method?

Comment: I'd do this directly using either `firewalld` or `iptables`.

Comment: As you found out, the best option is not relaying it at all

Comment: Can you describe this "real-time live stream" in a bit more detail? Is it really a stream? or are there requests/replies involved? Are you using any other options to socat besides those quoted? Have a look at `rcvbuf/rcvlowat/rcvtimeo/sndbuf/sndlowat/sndtimeo` options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on `socat`, but after a quick view to its name (SOcket CAT), it seems that it goes through opening two sockets and operating them in user-space.

As slm suggests, why do not configuring it via `iptables`?

Iptables is a user-space application which configures netfilter. Netfilter code is embedded in the kernel. It may result in a better performance, since  forwarded packet does not need to be passed from kernel-space to user-space and vice versa.

#### Resources

- https://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Answer (score 1):

In firewalld:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade

$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone="public" \
   --add-forward-port=port=8080:proto=tcp:toport=80:toaddr=123.123.123.123
```

For `iptables` see this SF Q&A titled: [How to do the port forwarding from one ip to another ip in same network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/586486/how-to-do-the-port-forwarding-from-one-ip-to-another-ip-in-same-network).

#### References

- [Introduction to FirewallD on CentOS](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/introduction-to-firewalld-on-centos/)
- [Forward a TCP port to another IP or port using NAT with Iptables](http://jensd.be/343/linux/forward-a-tcp-port-to-another-ip-or-port-using-nat-with-iptables)